# Radio Button value not in params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, radio-button

I have a problem with the params. Mainly, a value that I expect to be there, isn't there. I have a layout with some radio buttons. The idea is that when I select one of the radio buttons, the value should be present in `params[:answer]`. However, this value is `NIL`, so it is never updated and I'm not sure why. Here is my code (modified slightly to remove the non-relevant parts).

In a view `question/sub_view.html.erb`, I have the following radio buttons:

```
<div id="radio_buttons">
  <%= radio_button_tag :submit, name: 'answer', value: 'answer_1' %>Answer 1<br>
  <%= radio_button_tag :submit, name: 'answer', value: 'answer_2' %>Answer 2<br>
</div>
```

And I have a view `question/question.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Question</h1>
<div align="center">
  <%= render partial: "question/sub_view" %>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
  <%= link_to "Next", question_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

And in `routes.rb`:

```
get 'question' => 'question#question'
```

Now the important bit, in the `QuestionController.rb`, I have the following:

```
class QuestionController < ApplicationController

  def question
    puts params # print to console to check the parameters

    # stuff omitted that is not relevant
  end
end
```

I would expect that `params` contains the value `'answer'` (for instance, `'answer'=>'answer_1'`). Why is this the case?

Comment: Look at the generated html and you will see why it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the right syntax for this method. I added labels for good measure too.

```
<% = radio_button_tag :answer, 'answer_1', checked: true %>
<% = label :answer, 'Answer 1' %>

<% = radio_button_tag :answer, 'answer_2', checked: true %>
<% = label :answer, 'Answer 2' %>
```

> radio_button_tag(name, value, checked = false, options = {})

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-radio_button_tag

Comment: Thanks, though it still doesn't work, ```'answer'``` is still not present in the ```params``` map. So perhaps the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: I tried it and this code works. What is the output of your `params`?

Comment: If I put `params` to console I get: `{"action"=>"question", "controller"=>"question"}`

Comment: After you've submitted the form? Then you're doing something wrong in the controller.

Comment: or the form is wrong and doesn't even include the radio buttons. You can update the question with your whole form.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by submitting the form? I assumed that the button does this: `<%= link_to "Next", question_path, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>`.

Comment: No, the `link_to` doesn't submit the form. It's only a link.

Comment: That does make sense, though I'm not sure what the best way is too fix it now. How do I make sure that when I submit, it links to `question`?

Comment: Here is a very good overview dealing with forms http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: After some digging around I found the solution: I made it a form, used `submit_tag` for the button, added the `question` action as `action` parameter to the form and added a `post` to `routes.rb`. (Hopefully not too cryptic an explenation).

Comment: No no, there are plenty of ways to do this, as long as its working for you it's all good I guess.